# why my App has two manifest files

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio, android-manifest

I opened android project in android studio and I found that that project contains two manifest files as shown below in the image.

the first manifest contains the activities in the projects while the other manifest contains the permissions!!

please let me know how that is possible and why??

Note: I used to work with eclipse and I have not seen that feature before

**image**-,

[image]

Comment: library has it's own manifest

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the directory structure you see two projects: your app and a library project. So one Manifest-file is for your App and the other is for your the Library-project.

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot you have attached shows that you have been created a project and then added a library file for support. Remove the library if you don't need of that.

Right click on project->Build Path->Configure Build Path->Library

Select that library and remove. Now check your project.